# How to check for state in ec2_ami_facts

Tags: ansible, ec2-ami

ec2_ami_find is deprecated and ec2_ami_facts have to be used instead. In ec2_ami_find, we had to provide the parameter to check the state which will match the ami state. How can we incorporate the similar check with ec2_ami_facts as 'state' parameter is a return value in ec2_ami_facts ?

```
- name: Checking availablity status of encrypted ami
    ec2_ami_find:
       ami_id: "{{ ami_id }}"
       region: "{{ec2_region}}"
       state: pending
    register: ami_facts
    until: ami_facts.results[0] is undefined
    retries: 50 
    delay: 30
```

```
  - name: Checking availablity status of encrypted ami
    ec2_ami_facts:
       image_ids: "{{ mr_ami_id }}"
       region: "{{ ec2_region }}"
       #state: pending ?
    register: ami_facts
    until: ami_facts.results is undefined
    retries: 50 
    delay: 30
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in **the examples** section of [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/ec2_ami_facts_module.html), you will want to use the `filters:` sub-option to `ec2_ami_facts:` and then use the [documented filters list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html#API_DescribeImages_RequestParameters) to include the relevant constraints:

```
 -  name: Checking availablity status of encrypted ami
    ec2_ami_facts:
       image_ids: "{{ mr_ami_id }}"
       region: "{{ ec2_region }}"
       filters:
          state: pending
    register: ami_facts
```